# $_GET msg giving error when no msg travels in url

Tags: php, coding-style, phpmyadmin, web-deployment

i m using this piece of code when my login page authenticate me that this username or password is incorrect,

```
echo "<script languge='javascript'>location.href='index.php?msg=Incorrect UserName OR Password';</script>";
```

and i m using this code on my index.php to display the msg

```
echo $msg=$_GET["msg"];
```

But problem is when i go on index.php for putting my username and password and error comes instead of msg.

> Notice: Undefined index: msg in C:\wamp\www\CIT Site\admin\index.php on line 28

kindly tell me how do i get by default null msg and how should i print it without having any error statement.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: when i put wrong username or password it prints the msg correctly but first time when i visit to index.php it gives error

Comment: ..at first there's no such a thing like a "msg", but the next one it does!

Comment: @Shahjahan it says `notice` and not an error.. it should pass through just fine. if you wanna get rid of it, use `error_reporting(0);` on top of your php code..

Comment: Thanks brother for commenting, i got my solution in answers.

Comment: im just stating how to remove the notice as you asked, it was not covered on your accepted answer. ;)

Comment: Yeah that's right, but its ok you have told me good information which is surely gonna help me out. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check if the key exists in the array first

```
if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
    echo $_GET['msg'];
}
```

or you can use a shorthand ternary operator.

```
$msg = (isset($_GET['msg'])) ? $_GET['msg'] : null;
echo $msg;
```

As discussed in comments, if you're just echoing, do the following.

```
<?php echo (isset($_GET['msg'])) ? $_GET['msg'] : null; ?>
```

Comment: it is giving this error "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\wamp\www\CIT Site\admin\index.php on line 28
"

Comment: There is no syntax problem in the code provided, is this what is on line 28?

Comment: i m using this code "<?php 
     $msg = (isset($_GET[|"msg"])) ? $_GET["msg"] : null;
     echo $msg;
       ?>" gives error this "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting ']' in C:\wamp\www\CIT Site\admin\index.php on line 28
"

Comment: You have a rogue | (pipe) character in there, if you're just echoing then see my edit.

Comment: yeah i got it, Thank you soo very much for helping.. can u plz tell me how to put an automatically running clock in php? displaying time like 09:35 PM

Comment: Google is your friend on that one I'm afraid, PHP is capable of echoing the time, but not running the clock automatically, look at jQuery or vanilla JavaScript for a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

First i think you should change the msg get variable's value which is 'Incorrect UserName OR Password'. Change it to something else, maybe a number or something shorter. 5 or iup (incorrect username password).

this will be your url: index.php?msg=iup

then on index.php you need to check if the GET variable 'msg' is set, if it equals
iup, set the error variable

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['msg']))
{
  $messageValue = $_GET['msg'];

  if ($messageValue == 'iup')
  {
     //the incorrect username or password message was sent
     $error = "Incorrect UserName OR Password";
  }
}
?>
```

the above code should be placed at the start of the document above the html declaration.
we now open up a script somewhere in the body of the html document and echo the error message if the error varible isn't empty, it's important to check if it's empty and not just isset because in this case the isset will display an error if the error variable hasn't been assigned a value.

```
<?php
if (!empty($error))
{
   echo '<p>' . $error . '</p>';
}    
?>
```